# Write data to iPhone calendar (Titanium)

Tags: iphone, mobile, calendar, titanium

How can I write data into the iPhone's calendar using Appcelerator Titanium?

Thanks!

Tjellekes

Comment: You Can try this https://github.com/Mritunjaysingh/Titanium-Calendar. This is obviously working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Titanium doesn't natively support Calendar access.

However, there is this third-party [Titanium module](https://github.com/stelford/Titanium-Calendar) specifically for accessing the Calendar

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying it out, but how do I implement it? It says put the zip file in the Titanium folder, which I did.

But now when I run my test app it says it can't find the com.ti.calendar file. 

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Did you follow the part titled `REGISTER YOUR MODULE` ? Register your module with your application by editing `tiapp.xml` and adding your module i.e `<modules><module version="0.1">com.ti.calendar</module></modules>`

Comment: Yes, I have added that line in my tiapp.xml, but doesn't do anything.

I have the file "com.ti.calendar-iphone-0.1.zip" in my Titanium folder, or should this be another file? And I have also tried to rename it to "com.ti.calendar.zip" but that doesn't work either.

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest is did you get any errors when running `build.py`? Other than that I'm afraid I cannot help beyond what the read-me states as I have absolutely no experience with Titanium, I only develop for iOS natively.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway! I'll try some more.. The build.py was succesfully.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this personally, but here is something someone put together and posted on GitHub, might be helpful:

https://github.com/stelford/Titanium-Calendar

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The stelford library actually has to be modified to request calendar access. See this post:
[Titanium Force Calendar Access Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718118/titanium-force-calendar-access-request)